# Having two values on SelectList() in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to develop a website using `asp.net mvc 4` & `EF6` where I'm using `dropdownlist` to assign datas to my required textboxes. So far I've managed to assign data to two textboxes where one holds the value of the selected item of dropdownlist & one holds the text given for the selected item. But I need to add another value from the selected item. My codes are below,

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.Clients = new SelectList(db.ClientInfoes, "age", "fullname");    //This is given
ViewBag.Clients = new SelectList(db.ClientInfoes, "id", "age", "fullname");    //I want something like this
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Clients", "Select...")

// Textboxes are populated automatically by using jQuery
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Fullname, new { id = "clientName", @readonly = "readonly" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Age, new { id = "clientAge", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

How can I assign more than one value in the `SelectList`? Any way I can do that would be fine. Need this help badly. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the current test is and what sample of text do you want it to be ?

Comment: You cant. Use javascript/jquery to handle the dropdown's `.change()` event, call a controller method passing the selected value and return json with the values. But why populate readonly textboxes?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to show name and age both in the dropdown text, in that case you need to project the result coming from database :

```
var ClientInfoes = db.ClientInfoes
                     .Select(x=>
                             new {
                                    id = x.id,
                                    name = x.fullname+","+x.age 
                                 });

ViewBag.Clients = new SelectList(ClientInfoes, "id", "name");
```